# How can I debug "Back Navigation Caching" in IE?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, caching, internet-explorer-11

I'm seeing an odd bug in IE that I'm not seeing in Chrome.  Specifically, this involves some JS code not firing when a (Telerik) wizard is navigated back to it's first step.

When the user clicks their "Previous" button, some data isn't being properly loaded.  Hitting F12 and bringing up the developer console has shown me the following Warning:

> DOM7011: The code on this page disabled back and forward caching. For more information, see: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=291337

Ok, so I go to the link provided and I noticed the documentation states:

```
In order to be cached, webpages must meet these conditions:
...
 - The F12 Developer tools window isn't open
```

This is a problem, because when I use the navigation buttons within my wizard WHILE the dev window is open, it behaves properly, just as it does in Chrome.

How can I debug my related Javascript so I can figure out what's going on?  Also, I understand what caching is but I'm not exactly sure what this is about and I have no idea why Chrome behaves differently.  Is there a way that I can force IE to behave like chrome and cut on (or off) whatever features that are causing this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yuck. Back to old school debugging for you.

Short of putting the whole browser into a Windows debugger, you can pretty much forget about setting breakpoints. All you can do is log.

If you are lucky and your problem isn't too deep, you can use a sprinkling of simple `alert()` statements to let you know the state of things at various stages in your code. One nice thing is that you can serialize objects now pretty nicely; for example, you can do `JSON.stringify(this)`, which will probably give you a giant output, which you can copy and paste into your IDE and unpack. A major upside to doing this is that the alert will block, so you can take your time studying the output. A major downside to this is that race conditions are now much more likely.

Alternatively, you can add a `<textarea>` to the page and throw your `JSON.stringify(this)` results into that. Because this means extra DOM mutations, it also increases the odds of race conditions, but not by much. (If race conditions are a possibility, you can do this:

```
(function () {
    var currentState = JSON.stringify(this);
    setTimeout(function () {
        document.querySelector('textarea').value = currentState;
    }, 1000);
})()
```

Even though these are now asynchronous, if you use this multiple times in sequence, these will execute in that same sequence (unless you change the timeout period).

If you are doing actual page navigations (and not just changing the URL with `pushState()`), then actually reading those logs is going to be a problem. The solution is to put the page in a frame and write the content out to a sibling frame. As long as both frames are running on the same domain, you will have no problem pushing the data into the sibling frame. If you can't put them on the same domain, you are kind of screwed.

Comment: alerts + JSON.stringify() helped me get what I needed.  Thank you.