# DOM7011: The code on this page disabled back and forward caching

Tags: angular, internet-explorer, angular7

I'm testing my Angular app on IE 11 and unfortunately, it shows a bank page, I've un commented necessary lines in `polyfills` file and I can see login page, but even entering the right credentials, the response is 200 ok and I got the required info to login but it doesn't redirect to home page, and I can see this msg in console 
`DOM7011: The code on this page disabled back and forward caching.` it's not an error

I read a lot on stackoverflow and know that this question has been asked before, but none of suggested ideas work with me
the app works fine in all browsers like (chrome, firefox, Edge, opera)
Any suggestion is much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was in login component when get the credentials and navigate to home page, but it seems that it didn't work in IE, so the solution was to replace 
`this.router.navigate(['/']);`
by 
`this.router.navigate(['/home']);`

The second one, IE doesn't explore Date.parse, it gives different results in chrome and IE, so I replace it also.

Answer (score 1):

Besides uncomment all the import lines in polyfills.ts, have you installed the following packages with npm?

```
npm install --save classlist.js 
npm install --save web-animations-js
```

About the DOM7011 warning, from the [official doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/dev-guides/dn265017(v%3Dvs.85)) of Microsoft, the back navigation caching must meet the following conditions, you could first check if the page of your app meets these conditions:

> - Served using the **HTTP**: protocol (HTTPS pages are not cached for security reasons)
> - Page has **no beforeunload** event handlers defined
> - All **load** and **pageshow** events have completed
> - The page doesn't contain any of the following:
>
>   - Pending **indexedDB** transactions
>   - Open or active **web socket** connections
>   - Running **web workers**
>   - Microsoft **ActiveX** controls
> - The **F12 Developer tools** window isn't open

You could also refer to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35203059/how-can-i-debug-back-navigation-caching-in-ie) to debug back navigation caching in IE11. If the issue still occurs it could be better if you share a simple sample which helps reproduce it.

Comment: Thanks for answering! even with reviewing it but still not able to got it work!

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing this problem. I just uncomment below portion from polyfills.ts

```
***************************************************************************************************
 * BROWSER POLYFILLS
 */

/** IE9, IE10, IE11, and Chrome <55 requires all of the following polyfills.
 *  This also includes Android Emulators with older versions of Chrome and Google Search/Googlebot
 */

import 'core-js/es6/symbol';
import 'core-js/es6/object';
import 'core-js/es6/function';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-int';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-float';
import 'core-js/es6/number';
import 'core-js/es6/math';
import 'core-js/es6/string';
import 'core-js/es6/date';
import 'core-js/es6/array';
import 'core-js/es6/regexp';
import 'core-js/es6/map';
import 'core-js/es6/weak-map';
import 'core-js/es6/set';
```